# I need to create a function that gets passed multiple lists and returns a string to then be printed

Tags: python

I need to create a function that gets passed multiple lists and returns a string to then be printed. Honestly I don't even know if I am headed in the right direction or not.

```
wordlist = ['new', 'barn', 'shark', 'hold', 'art', 'only', 'eyes'],
['subtract', 'add'],
['girl', 'house', 'best', 'thing', 'easy', 'wrong', 'right', 'again', 'above'],
['question'],
[]


def createSentence(wordlist):
    if len(wordlist) > 1:
        return 'The ' + str(len(wordlist)) + ' sight words for this week are ' + wordlist + '.'
    elif len(wordlist) == 1:
        return 'The only sight word for this week is' + wordlist + '.'
    elif len(wordlist) == 0:
        return 'There are no new sight words for this week!'

print(createSentence(wordlist))
```

Also i think my lists should really look like this

```
week2 = ['new', 'barn', 'shark', 'hold', 'art', 'only', 'eyes']
week5 = ['subtract', 'add'] 
week10 = ['girl', 'house', 'best', 'thing', 'easy', 'wrong', 'right', 'again', 'above']
week13 = ['question']
week17 = []
```

But I don't know how to them pass them through to the function

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
wordlist = [['new', 'barn', 'shark', 'hold', 'art', 'only', 'eyes'],
            ['subtract', 'add'],
            ['girl', 'house', 'best', 'thing', 'easy', 'wrong', 'right', 'again', 'above'],
            ['question'],
            []]


def createSentence(wordlist):
    if len(wordlist) > 1:
        return f'The {len(wordlist)} sight words for this week are {", ".join(wordlist)}.'
    elif len(wordlist) == 1:
        return f'The only sight word for this week is {wordlist[0]}.'
    elif len(wordlist) == 0:
        return 'There are no new sight words for this week!'

for lst in wordlist:
    print(createSentence(lst))
```

Output:

```
The 7 sight words for this week are new, barn, shark, hold, art, only, eyes.
The 2 sight words for this week are subtract, add.
The 9 sight words for this week are girl, house, best, thing, easy, wrong, right, again, above.
The only sight word for this week is question.
There are no new sight words for this week!
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the words print out without the brackets around them?

Comment: @Victoria I added it.

Comment: @Victoria Let me know if you want to keep the quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to convert the list in a string by using the join function.

(' ,').join(wordlist)

```
week2 = ['new', 'barn', 'shark', 'hold', 'art', 'only', 'eyes']
week5 = ['subtract', 'add'] 
week10 = ['girl', 'house', 'best', 'thing', 'easy', 'wrong', 'right', 'again', 'above']
week13 = ['question']
week17 = []


def createSentence(wordlist):
    if len(wordlist) > 1:
        return 'The ' + str(len(wordlist)) + ' sight words for this week are ' + (' ,').join(wordlist)  + '.'
    elif len(wordlist) == 1:
        return 'The only sight word for this week is' + (' ,').join(wordlist) + '.'
    elif len(wordlist) == 0:
        return 'There are no new sight words for this week!'
```

Output for week2:
`'The 7 sight words for this week are new ,barn ,shark ,hold ,art ,only ,eyes.'`

Comment: I missplaced the coma, but that shouldn't be an issue:
`(' ,').join(wordlist)` --> `(', ').join(wordlist)`

Comment: The OP wants to pass all the lists into the function.

Comment: Yes, how would I then pass each of those lists through the function?

Comment: It depends in how you want the result, it come to my mind creating a list with the results in this case you can use comprehensions, like this:
`results = [createSentence(singlewordlist) for singlewordlist in wordlists]` where `wordlists` is a list of lists. Tell me if it works for you, sorry for answering too late.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a different approach by creating a data structure for your data -- in this case, a dictionary:

```
wordlists = {
    'week 2': ['new', 'barn', 'shark', 'hold', 'art', 'only', 'eyes'],
    'week 5': ['subtract', 'add'],
    'week 10': ['girl', 'house', 'best', 'thing', 'easy', 'wrong', 'right', 'again', 'above'],
    'week 13': ['question'],
    'week 17': [],
}

def createSentence(week):
        wordlist = wordlists[week]

        length = len(wordlist)

        if length > 1:
            return "The {} sight words for {} are: {}.".format(length, week, ", ".join(wordlist))

        if length == 1:
            return "The only sight word for {} is: {}.".format(week, ", ".join(wordlist))

        return "There are no new sight words for {}!".format(week)

for week in wordlists:
    print(createSentence(week))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
The 7 sight words for week 2 are: new, barn, shark, hold, art, only, eyes.
The 2 sight words for week 5 are: subtract, add.
The 9 sight words for week 10 are: girl, house, best, thing, easy, wrong, right, again, above.
The only sight word for week 13 is: question.
There are no new sight words for week 17!
>
```